# How to use multiple Jelly files in one Jenkins plugin

Tags: jenkins-plugins, jelly

How do you make sure that a specific jelly file gets used? I am trying to write  a plugin for Jenkins, with 3 functionalities

1. To set a system configuration value.
2. To set a Post build step value and
3. To set a post build action value.

The first two functions  are working fine, however for the post build action i am unable to get the field values to show up from the jelly file.
The first two functions are implemented with one java file and a jelly file while the third one is implemented using another java file and another jelly file.

Any help is appreciated.
[image: screenshot1]
[image: screenshot2]

Jelly file content:

```
<j:jelly xmlns:j="jelly:core" xmlns:st="jelly:stapler" xmlns:d="jelly:define" xmlns:l="/lib/layout" xmlns:t="/lib/hudson" xmlns:f="/lib/form"> 
  <!-- This jelly script is used for per-project configuration. See global.jelly for a general discussion about jelly script. --> 

  <!-- Creates a text field that shows the value of the "name" property. When submitted, it will be passed to the corresponding constructor parameter. -->
  <f:entry title="Name" field="name"> 
    <f:textbox />
  </f:entry>
</j:jelly>
```

Comment: consider adding the content of your config.jelly

Comment: Jelly file content: <j:jelly xmlns:j="jelly:core" xmlns:st="jelly:stapler" xmlns:d="jelly:define" xmlns:l="/lib/layout" xmlns:t="/lib/hudson" xmlns:f="/lib/form">
  <!--
    This jelly script is used for per-project configuration.

    See global.jelly for a general discussion about jelly script.
  -->

  <!--
    Creates a text field that shows the value of the "name" property.
    When submitted, it will be passed to the corresponding constructor parameter.
  -->
  <f:entry title="Name" field="name">
    <f:textbox />
  </f:entry>
</j:jelly>